# laravel ckeditor installation

Tags: laravel, ckeditor

I have install Laravel previously and it works perfectly but now when I fire command `composer require unisharp/laravel-ckeditor` it installs `"unisharp/laravel-filemanager": "~1.8"`.

I have also try to install it using [this link](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/guide/dev_package_managers.html#composer) but its not worked..

I guess author have changes the package..

Anyone have any idea about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

```php
composer require ckeditor/ckeditor
```

result

```php
akash@localhost /var/www/html/lara57 $ composer require ckeditor/ckeditor

Using version ^4.11 for ckeditor/ckeditor
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Package operations: 1 install, 0 updates, 0 removals
  - Installing ckeditor/ckeditor (4.11.3): Downloading (100%)         
Package phpoffice/phpexcel is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use phpoffice/phpspreadsheet instead.
Writing lock file
```

Comment: The package not showing in composer.json file. is it shows in your file?

Comment: yes  "require": {
        "php": "^7.1.3",
        "anlutro/l4-settings": "^0.7.3",
        "ckeditor/ckeditor": "^4.11",
        "crocodicstudio/crudbooster": "^5.4",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.0",
        "laravel/framework": "5.7.*",
        "laravel/tinker": "^1.0",
        "tecnickcom/tcpdf": "^6.2",
        "themsaid/laravel-langman": "^1.3"
    },

Comment: its not contain publishable file