# intergrate ckeditor with laravel 6

Tags: laravel, ckeditor

I am trying to intergrate my laravel project with a text editor i.e Unisharp CKEditor v4.7. It has failed because it is not compatible with Laravel beyond Laravel version 5.8 How do I downgrade to Laravel 5.9? or else, is there any other alternative text editor I can use on Laravel 6?

I get the response below:

> Problem 1
>       - Installation request for unisharp/laravel-ckeditor ^4.7 -> satisfiable by unisharp/laravel-ckeditor[4.7.2].
>       - Conclusion: remove laravel/framework v6.2.0
>       - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.2.0
>       - unisharp/laravel-ckeditor 4.7.2 requires illuminate/support ~5.0 -> satisfiable by illuminate/support[5.0.x-dev, 5.1.x-dev, 5.2.x-dev, 5.3.x-dev, 5.4.x-dev, 5.5.x-dev, 5.6.x-dev, 5.7.17, 5.7.18, 5.7.19, 5.7.x-dev, 5.8.x-dev, v5.0.0, v5.0.22, v5.0.25, v5.0.26, v5.0.28, v5.0.33, v5.0.4, v5.1.1, v5.1.13, v5.1.16, v5.1.2, v5.1.20, v5.1.22, v5.1.25, v5.1.28, v5.1.30, v5.1.31, v5.1.41, v5.1.6, v5.1.8, v5.2.0, v5.2.19, v5.2.21, v5.2.24, v5.2.25, v5.2.26, v5.2.27, v5.2.28, v5.2.31, v5.2.32, v5.2.37, v5.2.43, v5.2.45, v5.2.6, v5.2.7, v5.3.0, v5.3.16, v5.3.23, v5.3.4, v5.4.0, v5.4.13, v5.4.17, v5.4.19, v5.4.27, v5.4.36, v5.4.9, v5.5.0, v5.5.16, v5.5.17, v5.5.2, v5.5.28, v5.5.33, v5.5.34, v5.5.35, v5.5.36, v5.5.37, v5.5.39, v5.5.40, v5.5.41, v5.5.43, v5.5.44, v5.6.0, v5.6.1, v5.6.10, v5.6.11, v5.6.12, v5.6.13, v5.6.14, v5.6.15, v5.6.16, v5.6.17, v5.6.19, v5.6.2, v5.6.20, v5.6.21, v5.6.22, v5.6.23, v5.6.24, v5.6.25, v5.6.26, v5.6.27, v5.6.28, v5.6.29, v5.6.3, v5.6.30, v5.6.31, v5.6.32, v5.6.33, v5.6.34, v5.6.35, v5.6.36, v5.6.37, v5.6.38, v5.6.39, v5.6.4, v5.6.5, v5.6.6, v5.6.7, v5.6.8, v5.6.9, v5.7.0, v5.7.1, v5.7.10, v5.7.11, v5.7.15, v5.7.2, v5.7.20, v5.7.21, v5.7.22, v5.7.23, v5.7.26, v5.7.27, v5.7.28, v5.7.3, v5.7.4, v5.7.5, v5.7.6, v5.7.7,
>   v5.7.8, v5.7.9, v5.8.0, v5.8.11, v5.8.12, v5.8.14, v5.8.15, v5.8.17, v5.8.18, v5.8.19, v5.8.2, v5.8.20, v5.8.22, v5.8.24, v5.8.27, v5.8.28,
>   v5.8.29, v5.8.3, v5.8.30, v5.8.31, v5.8.32, v5.8.33, v5.8.34, v5.8.35, v5.8.4, v5.8.8, v5.8.9].

Comment: That package abuses what composer is meant for: PHP packages. Try to use CKEditor as an `npm` package instead.

Comment: Just look at the single PHP file in the package: https://github.com/UniSharp/laravel-ckeditor/blob/master/ServiceProvider.php . Basically, this moves the ckeditor js files to your public folder, something for which you do not need a composer package.

Comment: @flame is right, not sure why this package exists in the first place. You can install the package with npm and create a javascript file with laravel mix and include in the page you want to use.

Answer (score 2):

I was having a problem with laravel v7.x and ckeditor integration.
So I've run:

```
composer require ckeditor/ckeditor
```

from this suggestion:

[laravel ckeditor installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55141494/laravel-ckeditor-installation)

and problem with laravel v7.x and ckeditor was resolved.

I hope that this will help someone :)

Answer (score -1):

The best option that worked for my project was downgrading lavarel version to v5.8 by deleting the 'composer.lock' file and 'vendor' folder then running 'composer install'.

Comment: cant believe youve actually answered your own question weeks later with the great solution of downgrading your laravel version.